# QGIS Loading GeoTiff at Origin

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff, geospatial-pdf, usgs

I have a GeoTiff that loads incorrectly in QGIS.

Instead of displaying the image at the correct coordinates, QGIS positions the raster with its upper left corner at (0,0).

This same file loads correctly in Google Earth, but for some reason QGIS isn't recognizing the georeferencing info.

The original motive was to load USGS topo quadrants into QGIS.  I downloaded the georeferenced PDF files available from USGS, then used GDAL to convert:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:32617 example_USGS_topo.pdf example_USGS_topo.tif --config GDAL_PDF_LAYERS "ALL" --config GDAL_PDF_LAYERS_OFF "Images" --config GDAL_PDF_DPI 300 --config GDAL_PDF_BANDS 3
```

More info on that in the helpful USGS instructions here: [Converting US Topo GeoPDF Layers to GeoTIFF](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiv-6GdqaTRAhUIyoMKHZDfAasQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fnationalmap.gov%2Fustopo%2Fdocuments%2Fustopo2gtif_current.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHq1EckV9I2L51lGqZrtZSdyz7Jww&sig2=od0zU00GiOue1WpW-t-wdQ)

If you'd like to work with the same USGS PDF file I'm using, here's a link to the original USGS ZIP containing the PDF. https://ims.er.usgs.gov/gda_services/download?item_id=8139809

Note that the above gdal_translate command applied to this example PDF produces a GeoTiff with the following gdalinfo output:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: NC_Ashford_20160624_TM_geo.tif
Size is 6825, 8700
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 17N",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-81],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32617"]]
GeoTransform =
  408447.1636098031, 2.03190732774024, -0.01942631127630456
  3972082.073249529, -0.01942631127630456, -2.03190732774024
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  AUTHOR=USGS National Geospatial Technical Operations Center
  CREATION_DATE=D:20160624090308Z
  CREATOR=ESRI ArcSOC 10.0.2.3200
  KEYWORDS=Topographic, Transportation, Hydrography, Orthoimage, U.S. National G
rid, imageryBaseMapsEarthCover, Imagery and Base Maps, Geographic Names Informat
ion System
  NEATLINE=POLYGON ((421074.64910106914 3970498.3348052166,420940.92899800668 39
56511.7959603746,409525.75346028153 3956620.932213902,409659.47356334399 3970607
.4710587487,421074.64910106914 3970498.3348052166))
  SUBJECT=This image map depicts geographic features on the surface of the earth
.  It was created to provide a representation of accessible geospatial data whic
h is readily available to enhance the capability of Federal, State, and local em
ergency responders for homeland security efforts.  This image map is generated f
rom selected National Map data holdings and other cartographic data.
  TITLE=USGS 7.5-minute image map for Ashford, North Carolina
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  408447.164, 3972082.073) ( 82d 0'51.74"W, 35d53'19.42"N)
Lower Left  (  408278.155, 3954404.479) ( 82d 0'51.18"W, 35d43'45.67"N)
Upper Right (  422314.931, 3971949.489) ( 81d51'38.62"W, 35d53'19.44"N)
Lower Right (  422145.922, 3954271.895) ( 81d51'39.16"W, 35d43'45.67"N)
Center      (  415296.543, 3963176.984) ( 81d56'15.18"W, 35d48'32.64"N)
Band 1 Block=6825x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=6825x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=6825x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Comment: Can you add a direct link for downloading the "NC_Ashford_20160624_TM_geo" map?

Comment: Offered by USGS as a ZIP containing the PDF.  Here's the link: https://ims.er.usgs.gov/gda_services/download?item_id=8139809

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the PDF from your link and used your gdal_translate command. My QGIS 2.16.2 opens the converted tiff file correctly with reasonable coordinates at the top left corner. It feels like it is your QGIS installation that has some issue.

[image]

Comment: Thanks user30184!  That really helps narrow down the problem.  I'm on 2.8.1 because installer for more recent version kept failing.  Sounds like I need to figure it out and upgrade.  Again, thanks for the help.